# objective c run file from code

Tags: objective-c

I used `[[NSWorkspace sharedworkspace] openFile:@"_file"]]` to run a command, and it worked perfectly when I run the app in Xcode. But when I tried to run my .app from finder and run the command it didn't work. The .command file is still inside the bundle.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: I would make sure you're still getting the right file path.

Comment: i'm not changing the code. everything remains the same, but when i run the app in xcode the command file runs, and when i'm trying the .app file (in Derived Data) nothing happens. (the app itself runs, the command doesn't)

Comment: That misses the point, sometimes running an application in Xcode will give a different path than one outside it.  You should have it print out the path in both cases to make sure they're the same.